# XAML Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2015

Подчеркивает кастом контролы и выдаёт `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

Проблема возникает только в дизайнер моде, если запустить приложение, то все работает нормально (Disable project code в xaml мне не подходит, т.к. окно (в редакторе) перестаёт отображаться корректно)

Нашел похожую проблему: 
[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3533539/wpf-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-in-designer)

XAML:

```
<local:CustomTextBox x:Name="secondNameTextBox"
                                 Grid.Row="0"
                                 Grid.Column="1"
                                 Height="25"
                                 CurrentDB="Персонал" />
```

Update:
Конструктор кастом контрола:

```
public CustomTextBox()
{
    OwnerWindow = Window.GetWindow(this);
}
```

Свойство OwnerWindow:

```
public Window OwnerWindow
    {
        get
        {
            return ownerwindow;
        }
        set
        {
            if (ownerwindow != null)
                return;
            ownerwindow = value;
            ownerwindow.LocationChanged += OwnerWindow_LocationChanged;
        }
    }
```

[Даже если закоментить весь сэттер свойства, всёравно ругается на NullReference.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbXIb.png)

StackTrace:

```
at SMNote_WPF.CustomTextBox.set_OwnerWindow(Window value)
   at SMNote_WPF.CustomTextBox.CustomTextBox_Loaded(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.BroadcastEventHelper.BroadcastEvent(DependencyObject root, RoutedEvent routedEvent)
   at System.Windows.BroadcastEventHelper.BroadcastLoadedEvent(Object root)
   at MS.Internal.LoadedOrUnloadedOperation.DoWork()
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireLoadedPendingCallbacks()
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireInvokeOnRenderCallbacks()
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandlerCore(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandler(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
```

Update 16.01.2016:

Благодаря Вам, удалось найти проблему. Проблема в `OwnerWindow = Window.GetWindow(this);`

Добавил проверку на null перед присвоением в конструкторе. Спасибо всем за помощь.

Comment: Где именно происходит ошикба? Какой там стектрейс?

Comment: В конструкторе контрола создается ивент Loaded, в этом ивенте вызавается OwnerWindow = Window.GetWindow(this);

Comment: Ну вот вы и нашли ошибку...

Comment: Если бы. Ошибка эта тут совсем не причем. Как видите значение проверяется на null, но всеравно он пытается присвоить ссылку

Comment: Не вижу. Совсем не вижу.

Comment: Результат дебага я опубликовал выше

Comment: Вы напрасно думаете что кто-то будет смотреть ваши скриншоты.

Comment: На этом сайте принято выкладывать код, а не картинки.

Comment: Value проверил для наглядности, в боевом коде этой проверки нет. Повторюсь. Код рабочий. Ошибка возникает во время работы с дизайнером xaml, если сбилдить приложение, то оно прекрасно работает.

Comment: @AK он, как и должен, равен null. Именно для этого я присваиваю ему value. Которая null быть не должна. Запустится комп, выложу больше кода

Comment: Ввел в заблуждение предидущим коментом. Не сбилдить, а запустить приложение

Comment: @DenisJNewb: Покажите побольше кода. Что в вашем `CustomTextBox_Loaded`? У вас в `OwnerWindow` записывается `null`.

Comment: `public CustomTextBox()
        {
            Loaded += CustomTextBox_Loaded;
            TextChanged += CustomTextBox_TextChangedAsync;
            IsLoading = true;
            ContextMenu = new MyContextMenu(this);
            searchMenu = new SearchMenu(this);
        }`  `private void CustomTextBox_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OwnerWindow = Window.GetWindow(this); 
            SearchParameter = Name.Replace("TextBox", "");
        }`

Comment: @DenisJNewb: В редакторе, понятно, `Window.GetWindow(this)` даёт `null`. Поэтому в сеттере `OwnerWindow` `value = null`, вот оно и падает на обращении `ownerwindow.LocationChanged`.

Comment: @VladD: Оно падает и без создания ивента, Выше я опубликовал результат выполнения кода пустого сэттера

Comment: @DenisJNewb: Если stack trace при этом такой же, значит, вы забыли сделать rebuild. Если не такой же, то давайте его в вопрос, посмотрим, где ещё проблемы.